# how to create django rest asynchronous APIView

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, async-await, python-asyncio

I have an ecommerce website developed using django rest framework version 3.14. In some days of month, we have a huge traffic of users trying to order. As the number of requests in some specific times are so big, a few of them will fail.

I think one solution is to use **asynchronous** APIs in backend. The views in django back are class based `APIView`. And I can not figure out how should I change the simple `APIView`s to **Async** views.

I also don't need to change all views, but 2 views that are handling purchase process.

In these 2 views, I have `post` and `get` methods, and some other methods that handle ORM calls (`filter`, `get`, `all`, etc.)

Any solution?